# How to simplify $4\cos20^{\circ}\sin10^{\circ}+2\sin 170^{\circ}-\cos 40^{\circ}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The problem is as follows:

Simplify the following expression:

$B=4\cos20^{\circ}\sin10^{\circ}+2\sin 170^{\circ}-\cos 40^{\circ}$

The alternatives given in my book are:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\cos 40^{\circ}\\
2.&2\cos^{2}70^{\circ}\\
3.&\sin 20^{\circ}\\
4.&1\\
5.&\sin^{2}70^{\circ}\\
\end{array}$

What I've attempted already was to use prosthaphaeresis formula to the first term in the equation and reduction to first quadrant for the second term but I end up with the third term which I don't know how to reduce it further.

$B=4\cos20^{\circ}\sin10^{\circ}+2\sin 170^{\circ}-\cos 40^{\circ}$

$B=2(\sin 30^{\circ}-\sin 10^{\circ})+2\sin 10^{\circ}-\cos 40^{\circ}$

$B=2\sin 30^{\circ}-2\sin 10^{\circ}+2\sin 10^{\circ}-\cos 40^{\circ}$

$B=2\sin 30^{\circ}-\cos 40^{\circ}$

$B=1-\cos 40^{\circ}$

Then what I would do is to multiply it by 2 and divide it by 2:

$B=2\times \frac{1-\cos 40^{\circ}}{2}$

$B=2\sin^2 20^{\circ}$

However this doesn't appear in the alternatives. Instead its cosine counterpart:

$B=2\cos^2 70^{\circ}$

But is it okay to use the cofunction that way. Does it exist another method to solve this problem?

Comment: Yeah what's wrong with that? You do know that, $\sin(90^{\circ} -\theta)=\cos(\theta)$, right?

Comment: As an alternative, you could try, without the cofunction, to reverse the problem, and get the original statement from the end result.

Answer (score 1):

$4\cos 20°\sin 10°+2\sin 170°-\cos 40°\\ \begin{align} &= 2(2\cos 20°\cos 80°) +2\sin 10°-\cos 40°\\ &=2(\cos 100°+\cos 60°) +2\sin 10°-\cos 40°\\ &=-2\sin 10°+1+2\sin 10°-\cos 40°\\ &=1-2\cos 40°\\ &=2\sin ^220°=2\cos^270° \end{align}$

---

Here is used $2\cos x.\cos y= \cos (x+y)+\cos (x-y)\;\text{and}\;\displaystyle 1-\cos x= 2\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}$.

Comment: Typeset mathematical terms using MathJax rather than posting image. You can find the tutorial on meta of this site.